# How to install drivers for Canon MX920 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, printing, pdf

I am trying to print pdf's on a Canon MX920 from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but it says there is no printer installed.  I can't install the printer - it says it can't find drivers.  I can print just fine from libre office.  I went to Canon's drivers page and downloaded the source file for a linux driver.  The readme file say to use the command *rpmbuild* which doesn't seem to exist for me. So I used *apt install rpm* and that installed the packages.  I still can't add the printer. Can someone help me from here?

Comment: Please always FIRST look in ubuntu software center, then on launchpad. After you exhausted those options ask on askubuntu. All other options offered should be neglected unless explained on AU.

Comment: Use either https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon  or https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk  Those PPA hold all generic drivers for Canon printers.

Answer (score 2):

Canon have provided a driver for this device since 2013; so if you go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100517002.html and click to download and **save** what will be **cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb.tar.gz**

if you open a terminal; copy the commands below; line by line; paste into the terminal; hit the ENTER key for each command then move to the next line

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb.tar.gz
cd cnijfilter-mx920series-3.90-1-deb
```

then run the install script; watch as it runs as it may ask you questions

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

that should install the drivers and register the printer and you should be good to go

(I thought michael gruz ppa was no longer supported ........)

Comment: michael gruz ppa still works. Old and unmaintained yes, but the drivers still work.

Comment: Link does not work anymore.

Comment: New link seems to be https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/mx-series-inkjet/mx922. Then under operating system select `Linux` instead of `Linux 64bit`.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the US Canon site and look for drivers for the MX920 printer, you will get the message:
"There is no driver for the OS Version you selected. The driver may be included in your OS or you may not need a driver."
when the website has automatically detected that you are running a Debian 64-bit or 32-bit OS (e.g. Ubuntu), but if you scroll (pull) further down the list you will find that if you simply select "Linux" as your operating system you will be able to download the 3.90 version of the drivers.  Source code is also available for download.

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/mx-series-inkjet/mx922?tab=drivers_downloads